# How to show loading gif before fetching text in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to php result but before fetching it, loading gif image should display in div section.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>
      CTR Calculator Tool | Free Click Through Rate Online Calculator
    </title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="myForm" method="post">
      Clicks: <input name="name" id="name" type="text" /><br />
      Impressions: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

      <input
        type="button"
        id="submitFormData"
        onclick="SubmitFormData();"
        value="Submit"
      />
    </form>
    <br />
    Your data will display below..... <br />
    ==============================<br />

    <div id="loader" style="display: none">
      <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />
      <!-- All data will display here  -->
    </div>
    <div id="results"></div>

    <script>
      function SubmitFormData() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();

        $.post("submit.php", { name: name, email: email }, function (data) {
          $("#results").html(data);
          $("#myForm")[0].reset();
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to show loading image before fetching result from server. But getting problem

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the form. change the div display style to block. when the response comes back, change it back to none.

extra note. i would suggest converting the current callback added to the $post method to a promise/async-await since callbacks can be confusing.

```js
 function SubmitFormData() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
        loader.style.display = "block";  
    $.post("submit.php", {name: name, email: email},
       function(data) {
         $('#results').html(data);
         $('#myForm')[0].reset();
         loader.style.display = "none";
       });
}

//or just use async/await which is easier

async function SubmitFormData() {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var loader = document.getElementById("loader");
    loader.style.display = "block";  
    const data = await $.post("submit.php", {name: name, email: email});
    $('#results').html(data);
    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
    loader.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thanks its working now and what is asyn await?

Comment: What does meant it? extra note. i would suggest converting the current callback added to the $post method to a promise/async-await since callbacks can be confusing.

Comment: @Learner_1 - please read this article : https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/callback-vs-promises-vs-async-await/#:~:text=The%20await%20keyword%20is%20used,the%20use%20of%20callbacks%20in%20.&text=In%20using%20async%20and%20await,prepended%20when%20calling%20a%20promise.

Comment: Can you send me updated code then with asyn callback? I didnt understand it because i have used php to fetch using post method

Comment: I edited the post. please take a look @Learner_1

Comment: Would really appreciate if you accept the answer man (:  i did my best to help you.

Comment: But you can still accept it my friend @Learner_1 (:

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery

```
$("#loader").show();
$("#loader").hide()
```